# Drawing under a curve in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a subplot (`self.intensity`), I want to shade the area under the graph.

I tried this, hoping it was the correct syntax:

```
self.intensity.fill_between(arange(l,r), 0, projection)
```

Which I intend as to do shading for `projection` numpy array within `(l,r)` integer limits.

But it gives me an error. How do I do it correctly?

---

Heres the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py", line 1289, in _onLeftButtonDown
    FigureCanvasBase.button_press_event(self, x, y, 1, guiEvent=evt)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1576, in button_press_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, mouseevent)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 265, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 191, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/spectrum/plot_handler.py", line 55, in _onclick
    self._call_click_callback(event.xdata)
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/spectrum/plot_handler.py", line 66, in _call_click_callback
    self.__click_callback(data) 
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/spectrum/plot_handler.py", line 186, in _on_plot_click
    band_data  = self._band_data)
  File "/root/dev/spectrum/spectrum/plot_handler.py", line 95, in draw
    self.intensity.fill_between(arange(l,r), 0, projection)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 6457, in fill_between
    raise ValueError("Argument dimensions are incompatible")
ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible
```

Comment: We'll need a bit more information than that. What are `l`, `r` and `projection`? The traceback is telling you that `arange(l,r)` is not the same length as `projection`. Did you mean to include the value of `r` in the sequence generated by `arange`, i.e. `arange(l,r+1)`?

Comment: Edited my question. I hope it contains all relevant info? And it is `scipy.arange` imported into global namespace. And I intend the `arange` to generate the limits for `projection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to fill the part of the projection from l to r. fill_between expects the x and y arrays to be of equal lengths, so you can not expect to fill part of the curve only.

To get what you want, you can do either of the following:
1. send only part of the projection that needs to be filled to the command; and draw the rest of the projection separately. 
2. send a separate boolean array as argument that defines the sections to fill in. See the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between)!

For the former method, see the example code below:

```
from pylab import *

a = subplot(111)

t = arange(1, 100)/50.
projection = sin(2*pi*t)

# Draw the original curve
a.plot(t, projection)
# Define areas to fill in
l, r = 10, 50
# Fill the areas
a.fill_between(t[l:r], projection[l:r])
show()
```

Comment: Great! Using `projection[l:r]` fixed it!